# How to apply a function once during simplification in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

From what I understand, function calls in Coq are opaque. 
Sometimes, I need to use `unfold` to apply it and then `fold` to turn the function definition/body back to its name. This is often tedious. My question is, is there an easier way to let apply a specific instance of a function call?

As a minimal example, for a list `l`, to prove right-appending `[]` does not change `l`:

```
Theorem nil_right_app: forall {Y} (l: list Y), l ++ [] = l.
Proof.
  induction l. 
    reflexivity.
```

This leaves:

```
1 subgoals
Y : Type
x : Y
l : list Y
IHl : l ++ [] = l
______________________________________(1/1)
(x :: l) ++ [] = x :: l
```

Now, I need to apply the definition of `++` (i.e. `app`) once (pretending there are other `++` in the goal which I don't want to apply/expand). Currently, the only way I know to implement this one time application is to first unfold `++` and then fold it:

```
    unfold app at 1. fold (app l []).
```

giving:

```
______________________________________(1/1)
x :: l ++ [] = x :: l
```

But this is inconvenient as I have to figure out the form of the term to use in `fold`. I did the computation, not Coq. My question boils down to:

Is there a simpler way to implement this one-time function application to the same effect?

Comment: All Coq's definition are not opaque, but there are ways to prevent Coq from unfolding a definition automatically (e.g. using `Qed`. instead of `Defined` when defining a function using tactics).

Comment: what do you mean by Opaque?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `simpl`, `compute` or `vm_compute` if you want to ask Coq to perform some computation for you. If the definition of the function is `Opaque`, the above solution will fail, but you could first prove a rewriting lemma such as:

```
forall (A:Type) (a:A) (l1 l2: list A), (a :: l1) ++ l2 = a :: (l1 ++ l2).
```

using your technique, and then `rewrite` with it when necessary.

Here is an example using `simpl`:

```
Theorem nil_right_app: forall {Y} (l: list Y), l ++ nil = l.
Proof.
(* solve the first case directly *)
intros Y; induction l as [ | hd tl hi]; [reflexivity | ]. 
simpl app. (* or simply "simpl." *)
rewrite hi.
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

To answer your comment, I don't know how to tell `cbv` or `compute` to only compute a certain symbol. Note that in your case, they seem to compute too eagerly and `simpl` works better.

Comment: thanks. do you mean that I can use 'compute' like 'compute app at 1', or something similar? Could you give an example if so. I looked at coq doc for compute and cbv but couldn't find a concrete example.

Comment: Update with an example and a few words