# How to execute a computation exactly once in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have  a proof below with three more sub-goals to go. The proof is about the correctness of optimizing away `plus 0` (`optimize_0plus`) in a simply arithmetic language demonstrated [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Imp.html). `aexp` is "arithmetic expression" and `aeval` is "arithmetic evaluation".

```
3 subgoal
a1 : aexp
a2 : aexp
IHa1 : aeval (optimize_0plus a1) = aeval a1
IHa2 : aeval (optimize_0plus a2) = aeval a2
______________________________________(1/3)
aeval (optimize_0plus (APlus a1 a2)) = aeval (APlus a1 a2)
```

, where the `optimize_0plus` is:

```
Fixpoint optimize_0plus (a:aexp) : aexp :=
  match a with
  | ANum n =>
      ANum n
  | APlus (ANum 0) e2 =>
      optimize_0plus e2
  | APlus e1 e2 =>
      APlus (optimize_0plus e1) (optimize_0plus e2)
  | AMinus e1 e2 =>
      AMinus (optimize_0plus e1) (optimize_0plus e2)
  | AMult e1 e2 =>
      AMult (optimize_0plus e1) (optimize_0plus e2)
  end.
```

My war plan is to apply `optimize_0plus` in the LHS of the current sub-goal, and obtain:

```
aeval (APlus (optimize_0plus a1) (optimize_0plus a2)) = aeval (APlus a1 a2)
```

(But I can't figure out how to do this in Coq).

Then, through some `simpl`, obtain:

```
(aeval (optimize_0plus a1)) + (aeval (optimize_0plus a2)) = (aeval a1) + (aeval a2)
```

and apply the induction hypotheses `IHa1` and `IHa2` to complete the proof.

My question is:

How can I tell Coq to apply the definition of `optimize_0plus` exactly once, and **do no more and no less**?

I have tried `simpl optimize_0plus`, but it gives something with a long `match` statement, which seems to be doing too much. And I do not like to use the `rewrite` tactic every time to establish a lemma because this computation is exactly one step with paper and pencil.

Notes:

1.This is related to my [earlier question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060802/how-to-apply-a-function-once-during-simplification-in-coq), but the answers there about using `simpl XXX` does not seem to work here. This seems to be a more complicated case.

2.The original website offers a proof that works. But the proof there seems to be more complex than necessary as it begins to do case analysis on the terms `a1` etc.

```
  Case "APlus". destruct a1.
    SCase "a1 = ANum n". destruct n.
      SSCase "n = 0". simpl. apply IHa2.
      SSCase "n ≠ 0". simpl. rewrite IHa2. reflexivity.
    SCase "a1 = APlus a1_1 a1_2".
      simpl. simpl in IHa1. rewrite IHa1.
      rewrite IHa2. reflexivity.
    SCase "a1 = AMinus a1_1 a1_2".
      simpl. simpl in IHa1. rewrite IHa1.
      rewrite IHa2. reflexivity.
    SCase "a1 = AMult a1_1 a1_2".
      simpl. simpl in IHa1. rewrite IHa1.
      rewrite IHa2. reflexivity.
```

So, my concern is not really to prove this simple theorem, but on how to prove this intuitively as I would on paper.

-- UPDATE --

Thanks to @gallais, my original plan is incorrect as one can change

```
aeval (optimize_0plus (APlus a1 a2))
```

to

```
aeval (APlus (optimize_0plus a1) (optimize_0plus a2))
```

only for the cases where `a1` is not `ANum 0`. The `0` case has to be dealt with separately by `destruct a1.` as with the course website quoted in Note 2.

However, I still have the same question for the other cases, listed below, which I think my original plan should work:

```
5 subgoal
SCase := "a1 = APlus a1_1 a1_2" : String.string
Case := "APlus" : String.string
a1_1 : aexp
a1_2 : aexp
a2 : aexp
IHa1 : aeval (optimize_0plus (APlus a1_1 a1_2)) = aeval (APlus a1_1 a1_2)
IHa2 : aeval (optimize_0plus a2) = aeval a2
______________________________________(1/5)
aeval (optimize_0plus (APlus (APlus a1_1 a1_2) a2)) =
aeval (APlus (APlus a1_1 a1_2) a2)
...

______________________________________(5/5)
aeval (optimize_0plus (AMult a1 a2)) = aeval (AMult a1 a2)
```

For each of these 5 cases, it seems that one application (`beta` reduction??) of `optimize_0plus` should allow us to change e.g. (for `AMinus`)

```
aeval (optimize_0plus (AMinus a1 a2))
```

to

```
aeval (AMinus (optimize_0plus a1) (optimize_0plus a2))
```

, right?

If so, how can I do this one-step reduction?

Note:
I tried

```
Eval cbv beta in (aeval (optimize_0plus (AMinus a1 a2))).
```

And I couldn't even get `aeval (AMinus (optimize_0plus a1) (optimize_0plus a2))` as I'd like to using a `Eval` in the proof.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the equation you're hopping to rely on is simply not true. It cannot be the case that:

```
optimize_0plus (APlus a1 a2) = APlus (optimize_0plus a1) (optimize_0plus a2)
```

given the definition of `optimize_0plus` you have given: if `a1` is `ANum 0` then `optimize_0plus (APlus a1 a2)` will reduce to `optimize_0plus a2` alone and not an `APlus`-headed term.

However the main theorem you are trying to prove is indeed correct and can be proven by inspecting `a1`: is it `ANum 0` (in which case the first branch will be fired by a call to `simpl`) or is it not (in which case the second branch will be taken)?

As a rule of thumb, every time you want to prove a theorem about a function defined by pattern-matching / recursive calls, you need to go through the same series of case-analysis / induction hypothesis. This is what is usually referred to as **functional induction** or **induction on the call graph of the function**.

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing out my error about the `0` case. I've updated the question to be on the non-`0` cases. I think my original plan should work for each of these, right? If so, how can I do the one step reduction please.

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions here:

- state a rewriting lemma with exactly what you want, prove it and then use it. This is the best solution when you need to do a very complex rewriting, but it doesn't scale that nicely since you need to write a lemma for each of your situations. For example here you could state (and trivially prove using `simpl`):

  ```
    forall a1 a2, optimize_0plus (APlus a1 a2) = APlus (optimize_0plus a1) (optimize_0plus a2).
  ```
- If I recall correctly, `simpl` and others don't go under binders. You can use the `pattern` tactic to "extract" the part you want to simplify, so that `simpl` or `unfold` only perform on some sub-term of your expression. You should read [the documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic140) since it is a bit long to explain here.
- EDIT: I forgot to talk about the `replace` tactics, which act like the `rewrite` solution but will ask you to prove the lemma right away, as a subgoal.

Comment: `change` would work even better than `replace` since it does not need a proof

Comment: True, `change` is missing from my survey. However don't forget that `change` might fail if the conversion is not obvious to Coq, so both have to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it is not always easy to make Coq do as much computation as we want. But here, contrary to what you say, the first rewrite is not just a simple computation step. Indeed, `optimize_0plus` destructs its arguments once, but when it finds something of the form `APlus _ _`, it needs to destruct the first new argument, so here you need to destruct `a1` to compute.

However, your result is still true, and can be considered as a convenient helper lemma to prove the initial theorem.

```
Lemma optimize_0plus_aux : forall a1 a2,
  aeval (optimize_0plus (APlus a1 a2)) =
  aeval (APlus (optimize_0plus a1) (optimize_0plus a2)).
Proof.
Admitted.
```

Concerning your initial question about one-step computation, I have two tricks:

- I know you do not want to use `rewrite` each time, but according to me, having an equation lemma is the best way to apply a fixpoint once. Note that you can generally create this lemma automatically with `Functional Scheme`. Here,

  ```
  Functional Scheme optimize_0plus_ind := Induction for optimize_0plus Sort Prop.
  ```
- In rare cases, there is a function you never want to unfold during a proof. In such cases, you can temporary make the definition opaque with `Opaque <function>`. At the end of the proof, make it transparent again with `Transparent <function>`. However, I do not think it is a good style and do not suggest to use it.